# iAD - Ads not showing in iOS9

Tags: ios9, iad

After upgrading to iOS9 and later iAds not showing up.  As mentioned in iOS9 I have added AppTransportSecuritySettings even though iAds are not showing up.
     Is this is an apple issue or is there any other way to implement it.please post your replies.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS9 self.canDisplayBannerAds = true is not showing any ads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635714/ios9-self-candisplaybannerads-true-is-not-showing-any-ads)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked status of iAd on your iTunesConnect account? It might have deregistered or deactivated. You should re-register for iAd & test it on app once again.

Comment: if in this case ,its working on iOS8,but iOS9 and later it is not showing any ads(every time it calls iAds failure Delegate method). @Ganesh Joshi